# C++: how do I convert a string that's a unix time to *tm? (Error using strptime: "cannot convert 'String' to 'tm*' ")

Tags: c++, datetime, time, unix-timestamp

I am using an API to retrieve a UNIX time but it's coming in as a string i.e. "1539944398000"

I would like to convert this to a UNIX time so that I can manipulate it (and eventually extract just the hours/minutes to put in a print).

Here's the code that I tried:

```
String nextBusScheduled = client2.readStringUntil('<');
char bufScheduled[40];
strptime(bufScheduled, "%Y-%m-%d", nextBusScheduled);
```

And this is the error I got:

```
cannot convert 'String' to 'tm*' for argument '3' to 'char* strptime(const char*, const char*, tm*)'
```

Comment: In C there is no native `string` type. Is it a typedef to `char *`?

Comment: Is this C++?  Is `String` actually a `std::string` or something else?

Comment: If you have a string containing a Unix timestamp, you can convert it to `time_t` using `strtoll`, then to a `struct tm` by calling `localtime` or `gmtime`.

Comment: There's no `struct tm` variable in your code. The third argument to `strptime` is the `struct tm *` that it's supposed to decode into. So why are you passing something else? And why are you asking it to parse `%Y-%m-%d` when your input isn't in that format?

Comment: This isn't C. It looks more like Java.

Comment: 1539944398000 doesn't look like a Unix time.  If it were 1539944398, it would be a time during the day on October 19 (i.e. today).  But it looks like someone's giving it to you in microseconds instead.

Comment: Ugh I'm sorry. Yes it's C++ (I'm a dumb beginner). And yes it's in microseconds, but I still don't know how to get it into a unix time..

Comment: @garson See what Steve Summit said.

Comment: @garson Being a beginner and being considered _dumb_ doesn't necessarily coincide :3

Comment: @melpomene ok thanks i am trying that now

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks for the encouragement - it helps and sometimes i feel stupid for posting here!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  For this exercise, all you need is the `date.h` header (and no source):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    int64_t i;
    istringstream in{"1539944398000"};
    in >> i;
    sys_time<milliseconds> tp{milliseconds{i}};
    cout << tp << '\n';
    cout << format("%H:%M", tp) << '\n';
}
```

Just parse into a 64 bit integral type, and construct a `std::chrono::milliseconds` from that parse (so far this is just straight C++11).  Then you can construct a `sys_time<milliseconds>` from that.  `sys_time<milliseconds>` is just a type alias for `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds>`, or to put it more simply: a [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) with millisecond precision.

I show two ways of printing it out, which is where `date.h` really helps.  This example outputs:

```
2018-10-19 10:19:58.000
10:19
```

This code will port to C++20 by just removing `#include "date/date.h"` and `using namespace date;`.